# Arduino over Internet

Tags: arduino, ethernet

I built local web server on arduino and now i want to reach from anywhere to my arduino over internet. But i didn't find any good solution for my problem.

this is my static internet ip: AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA
this is my arduino's ip: BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB
this is my router's ip: CCC.CCC.CCC.CCC 
(port 80 is open)

I can reach with BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB ip on my pc while arduino connected to my pc. But I want to reach via AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA ip over the internet but how?.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: This is a question about routing: if your arduino was another PC the question would be the same. So it is not a good topic for EE.  Try [superuser.SE](http://superuser.com/) maybe?  Actually [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) would probably be even better.

Comment: sorry, i found a few arduino ethernet questions in here. thanks for your interests.

Comment: @angelatlarge Superuser is better. Serverfault is for corporate environment setups, not home/consumer.

Answer (score 4):

You have to configure your modem to forward AAA.AAA.AAA.AAA:80 to BBB.BBB.BBB.BBB:80. It is called 'Port Forwarding', sometimes to be found under gaming on your router.

Comment: i made it before, but nothing happened.

Comment: @user1136403 does it work with anything on your network, like a cell phone or another computer? Does your ISP block port 80 forwarding? You might need to do port 8080 or 8000. Did you set it up for standard port forwarding or dynamic/port knocking first (Some routers default to port knocking)? Did you forward both tcp and udp? Mainly, if this is working with any computer, not just one, on your network, then it's just a routing issue.